# Android Studio (Java) Increment Value in Firebase Real-time Database

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm having a problem updating the value in my Firebase real-time database when clicking the 2 imagebutton. This is a survey app that i'm creating. So, there's no need to retrieve and display the data on the app itself.

The buttons are working and it displays the data in firebase. Unfortunately, the two buttons only displays 1 as its value no matter how many times i've clicked the button. It doesn't update itself in the database.

```
 private int clickCount1 = 0;
 private int clickCount2 = 0;
 private DatabaseReference mDatabase;


 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

//Firebase Database
mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

likebutton = findViewById(R.id.imageButton11);
downbutton = findViewById(R.id.imageButton10);

//Like Button Action
        likebutton.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            incrementClickCount1();
            saveClickCountToDatabase1();
            animationView1.playAnimation();
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Landscape.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        });

 //Down Button Action
        downbutton.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            incrementClickCount2();
            saveClickCountToDatabase2();
            animationView2.playAnimation();
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, NotifActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        });
    }
    private void incrementClickCount1() {
        clickCount1++;
    }
    private void incrementClickCount2() {
        clickCount2++;
    }
    private void saveClickCountToDatabase1(){
        mDatabase.child("FeedBack").child("Likes").setValue(clickCount1);
    }
    private void saveClickCountToDatabase2(){
        mDatabase.child("FeedBack").child("Dislikes").setValue(clickCount2);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to increment a counter in the database, use its [atomic increment operation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#atomic_server-side_increments). For your structure, that'd look like this:

```
mDatabase.child("FeedBack").child("Likes").setValue(ServerValue.increment(1))
```